# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Vich\\UploaderBundle\\VichUploaderBundle' not found in /va r/app/current/app/AppKernel.php on line 25

Tags: php, html-lists

```
  $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
        new JMS\TranslationBundle\JMSTranslationBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
        new Maxmind\Bundle\GeoipBundle\MaxmindGeoipBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\KnpGaufretteBundle(),
        new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
        new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
 );
```

please let me know why is happened?.... we need to update composer?

it seems like there's a problem with the namespace?

Comment: have you checked this class found in appkernel.php ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a composer problem since the bundle declaration is already namespaced and I'm assuming you haven't monkied with how the AppKernel sets up it's autoloader.

Either you need to add the library to composer:

```
composer require vich/uploader-bundle:0.14.0
```

or if you've manually updated composer.json, you'll need to run:

```
composer update --lock
```

Which will install the dependency, update the lockfile, and re-generate your autoload.php file. These commands may or may not work depending on how you installed composer(may need to prepend commands with `php composer.phar` instead of `composer`). You'll need to figure that out for yourself. Also, you'll need to specify the version you want as well. I just chose the latest stable from [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/vich/uploader-bundle).

Comment: Updated the answer with working syntax. If you still don't understand, then you have some googling to do to learn about how to use composer.